# How many times is the entire universe destroyed in Futurama?

Tags: futurama

<del>At the end of *Bender's Big Score*, bender releases all of his time-travel copies at the same time causing the universe to cease existing (only Nibbler escapes by consuming himself, thereby exiting the universe).</del>

In *The Late Philip J. Fry* (S06E07) we witness the natural death and re-birth of the universe twice (?) by traveling forward in time.

Are there other times when the entire universe is destroyed, and if so, how many?

Comment: I wouldn't count the end of Bender's Big Score as one of the times the universe was destroyed, while yes it's damaged and there is tear to another universe (see The Beast With a Billion Backs) the current one isn't destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the two natural deaths of the universe that occur in the episode ["The Late Philip J. Fry"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Late_Philip_J._Fry), there's one other time the destruction of the universe is shown: the episode ["Anthology of Interest I"](http://theinfosphere.org/Anthology_of_Interest_I). However, this wasn't an *actual* destruction since it was basically a *simulation* of possible events illustrated by the [What-If Machine](http://theinfosphere.org/What-If_Machine) (in response to the question "What would happen if Fry never came to the future?").